# Issue in understanding Multiple Knapsack Problem IBM CPLEX

Tags: cplex, knapsack-problem, opl, simplex

I found this example in the IBM CPLEX Studio in OPL Examples. However, I am not able to understand these two lines in the program. Is it a special way to use **int** decision variables instead of **boolean**?

```
int MaxValue = max(r in Resources) Capacity[r];
dvar int Take[Items] in 0..MaxValue;
```

Why do we find the maximum value of the resource capacity? Can someone please explain the logic behind it. I am new to Linear programming but curious about this. I believed that I should use a boolean variable in such situations. Thanks in advance.

```
int NbItems = ...;
    int NbResources = ...;
    range Items = 1..NbItems;
    range Resources = 1..NbResources;
    int Capacity[Resources] = ...;
    int Value[Items] = ...;
    int Use[Resources][Items] = ...;
    int MaxValue = max(r in Resources) Capacity[r];
    
    
    dvar int Take[Items] in 0..MaxValue;
    
    maximize
      sum(i in Items) Value[i] * Take[i];
      
    subject to {
      forall( r in Resources )
        ct:
          sum( i in Items ) 
            Use[r][i] * Take[i] <= Capacity[r];
    }
    
    
    tuple TakeSolutionT{ 
        int Items; 
        int value; 
    };
    {TakeSolutionT} TakeSolution = {<i0,Take[i0]> | i0 in Items};
    execute{ 
        writeln(TakeSolution);
```

Answer (score 0):

If MaxValue was 1 then

```
dvar int Take[Items] in 0..MaxValue;
```

would be equivalent to

```
dvar boolean Take[Items];
```

Likewise

```
dvar int x in 0..2;
```

means x is either 0,1 or 2

which will the same result as

```
dvar int x;

subject to
{
  0<=x<=2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alex for replying. I have utmost respect for your work with CPLEX and I follow your work thoroughly. I have a follow-up question to understand the concept. What is the need of that step to declare a maximum value?  Is there any easier explain of this? Thanks again in adv